# Moving metadata storage for cluster jobs with snakemake

Tags: snakemake

I am using snakemake to submit jobs from an AFS filesystem to a HTCondor queue. The submission starts off fine. Jobs submit and complete successfully. But after a certain point, submission crashes with the following error:

```
OSError: [Errno 27] File too large: '/afs/cern.ch/work/a/avenkate/private/MyKstTauTau/.snakemake/metadata/cm9vdDovL2Vvc2xoY2IuY2Vybi5jaC8vZW9zL2xoY2IvdXNlci9hL2F2ZW5rYXRlL0tzdFRhdVRhdS9Cc0JrZ01DL1ByZXNlbC8yMDE2X01VLzIwMjBfMDQvMzY1OTMyLzM2NTkzMjE4Ny9udHVwbGVfVE0ucm9vdA=='
```

When I look up this error, I understand from https://sites.google.com/a/stanford.edu/rcpedia/how-do-i/why-do-i-keep-getting-errno-27-file-too-large that it has to do with AFS, and not snakemake. It seems to be a limit on the number of files in a directory in AFS (The error message itself is misleading. This file size of the metadata files is in bytes. But the filenames are long).

So I would like to know if there is any way of getting around this issue with metadata files piling up. I have 10268 files in my metadata directory when the crash happens, and all are from one snakemake run.

Is it possible to have snakemake not store the metadata files locally, but rather in the temp directory of whatever node the job runs on? I see in the command line options that we can specify `--shadow-prefix` to tell snakemake where to store the shadow directory. Is there a similar functionality for the metadata?

I would appreciate any input on this. My submit command is

````
snakemake     --cluster 'condor_qsub -V -l procs={threads}' --forceall    --latency-wait 30     --rerun-incomplete     --max-jobs-per-second 100     --printshellcmds     --restart-times 0     --local-cores 8     --keep-going     -j 100     -s Snakefile_Data   --shadow-prefix $TMPDIR/MyKstTauTau.snakemake```
````

Answer (score 0):

I never used AFS but it seems to work similar to slurm. I am guessing these metadata files are the stdout and stderr of the jobs. You should be able to redirect where stdout and stderr are stored with -o and -e according to this [man page](https://research.cs.wisc.edu/htcondor/manual/v8.6/condor_qsub.html).

So something like this should make snakemake (actually AFS) not make any of these files:

```
snakemake ... --cluster "condor_qsub -o /dev/null -e /dev/null ..."
```

**edit:**

So the metadata are **not** the stdout and stderr from condor, my bad. I can not really think of a "real" solution, but here are two options you could try:

1. Simply cleaning up the metadata with `snakemake --cleanup-metadata`. If you are lucky there is a lot of stuff from previous runs which can be deleted and solves the issue!
2. Use less parallel jobs. Even though 100 is not so much, for every job some metadata is tracked. So running less jobs would mean less metadata files.

Comment: Hi Maarten, Thanks for taking the time to look into this. 
By metadata, I am referring specifically to the .snakemake/metadata folder. This folder apparently contains information related to the processes being run, and lots of files (with very long filenames, like the one in my error message) build up in this folder, causing AFS to hit some limit and throw the error.
I am actually unsure of where condor is placing the stdout and stderr files right now, but I'll keep your point in mind for when I want to move them around.

Comment: @Arvind, I edited my answer. I can't think of a real solution, but maybe this helps. Good luck!

Comment: @Maarten-vd-Saande, cleaning up the metadata would be a solution if not for the fact that in my use case, I had >10K jobs in a single snakemake run, and thus so many metadata files were created. Your second suggestion is what I have been restructuring my code to do, by making less parallel jobs. Thanks again!